# Can I fix a background-image to its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, codepen

I'm making a carousel/slider and want to center the images. When I use `background-position: center;` they get stretched when I change the width. Can't figure out how to center the images and not stretch them when changing width.

I found out that if I use `background-attachment: fixed;` and `background-position: center;` It looks like what I want. But the pictures scroll with the page. How can I fix this?

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Tama3ti/pen/YzJRdgv)

```js
const images = [
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_1.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_2.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_3.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_4.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_5.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_6.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_7.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_8.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_9.jpg",
  "https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_10.jpg"
];
var currentImgIndex = 0;
var futureImgIndex = 1;

function switchBackground() {
  $('.current').toggleClass('shrink'); // slide the image to the left

  setTimeout(() => { // after sliding is done and we cant see the old image; switch the currentImage with the one that was the background image.
    currentImgIndex = (currentImgIndex + 1) % images.length;
    futureImgIndex = (futureImgIndex + 1) % images.length;

    $('.current').css('background-image', 'url("' + images[currentImgIndex] + '")');
    $('.future').css('background-image', 'url("' + images[futureImgIndex] + '")');

    $('.current').toggleClass('shrink'); // reset the sliding animation after the new image is set
  }, 600); // image switch is delayed 600ms because the sliding animation takes that long
}

setInterval(switchBackground, 4000);
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 50rem;
  margin-top: 12.5vh;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 19px 38px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 15px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 200vh;
}

.slide {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-position: center;
  /*
by using these two settings above it looks like how i want. But the scroll is fucked. If i dont use them the shrinking-image stretches/moves */

  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.current {
  background-image: url("https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_1.jpg");
}

.current.shrink {
  width: 0;
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.30005, 0.25, 0.05, 1);
}

.future {
  background-image: url("https://daimarubesso.com/assets/image/top/top_visual1_2.jpg");
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide future"></div>
    <div class="slide current"></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Tried moving the pictures with `background-position`, tried using  tags instead, I'm stuck :c.

Every comment appreciated, thanks.

Comment: remove `border-radius: inherit;` from `.slide`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`background-attachment: scroll;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m6y2z5e/)

Comment: fixes the scrolling but it looks like it moves the picture out of the way instead of overlapping it.

Comment: @tama3ti So, how do you want it to be? Can you describe that exactly? Or do you have a version that you want to replicate?

Comment: this is what i want to replicate: https://daimarubesso.com/en/
Here you can see that the pictures don't move to the left when they are changing.

Comment: @tama3ti Images move to the left in your example in the question (the codepen)?

Comment: Hard to explain, they are being overlapped from the right to the left. but the picture that is being overlapped does not move. If i use background-attachment: scroll; then the picture that is being overlapped moves.

Comment: @tama3ti [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k079gvce/), again, that's what you want right?

Comment: yes! but the pictures are not centered anymore